# Not able to parse Array of string with single quotes around key value names

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, parsing, jsonparser

I am trying to parse an array to JSON.parse which have single quotes around the keys and values.
But it is throwing following error.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1`

The array which I am passing is :

`["{'name': 'Jhon'}"]`

Somehow, this string is not throwing any error.

`['{"name": "Jhon"}']`

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON object names must be strings per the JSON spec. [ECMA-404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf)

The string specification to look at.

> A string is a sequence of Unicode code points wrapped with quotation marks (U+0022).

The object specification to look at.

> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly bracket tokens surrounding zero or more name/value pairs. A name is a string.

Which would make `{'name': 'Jhon'}` invalid since it violates both the string `'Jhon'` and name `'name'` specifications. Using double quotes is valid JSON `{ "name": "John" }`

Comment: Thanks @Philip  This answers my question. Guess i will need to change the format of data I am receiving.